# When using Google Translate's "website" functionality, do passwords entered go through Google?

Tags: privacy, google, data-leakage

I'm looking at the functionality offered by Google Translate's option to translate an entire website. It opens in a new tab with the domain `https://whatever-is-the-website-domain-com.translate.goog/`.

**I wonder - if I fill out and submit a form while browsing in this way - will the information be available to Google? E.g. login & passwords pairs?**

I suspect it will be, but would like it confirmed by someone who knows how it's implemented under the hood.

Note: the question is not about judging whether it's good, bad, risky, etc - but just about the technical facts behind this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Just because it does not translate keyed in fields does not mean it is not stored, it just does not translate that. It usually translates what is generated on the dom, however what you type into it doesn't. If you translate google, you will see the HTML generated for search suggestions gets translated in real time so it is not only on page load. If you press F12 to get the developer options and open the network tab, whenever you type into the search input it will fire a post to translate.googleapis.com, so evidently it is sent to googles translate API. It depends on how the credential fields have been setup to if it sends the details to google API, I tested a few fields on google and not all of them post data.

Answer (score -1):

Google Translate does not translate data found in HTML input fields. So any passwords you enter in input fields are safe.

Comment: I guess the answer is “Google could, if they were interested, and if there were no legal or other consequences if it was ever found out. “. Then we’d need to think about what benefits Google could have, and what consequences there would be. And Tim Smith has less to fear than Tim Cook.